# Finding the cardinality of the set of finite sequences that are composed of numbers 0-9 and of the set of monotone increasing sequences

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

> 1. Find the cardinality of the set of finite sequences that are composed of the numbers  $\{0...9\}$ that doesn't start in 0
> 2. Find the cardinality of the set of monotone increasing sequences of rational numbers.

For 1. there are 9 options for the first 'spot', then there are $10^{n-1}$ options where $n$ is the number of 'spots' in the sequence. So the total should be $9\cdot10^{n-1}$.

For 2. it's a subset of the set of all sequences and that has the same cardinality as the rational numbers, since every sequence can be represented as a unique rational number, like for example the sequence $243109$ is $2+4/10+3/100...$.

Is my approach correct ?

How it should be answered properly in a test ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1, you are correct for sequences of length $n$.  As I read the question, they want sequences of all finite lengths. The union of a countably infinite set of disjoint finite sets has cardinality $\aleph_0$

For 2, the numbers in the sequence are rationals, not digits, so your argument does not work.  Any subset of the naturals can be put in order, so there is one sequence for each subset of the naturals, which is $2^{\aleph_0}$   The sequences of rationals must be at least this many.  Since any monotone sequence must be an ordered subset of the rationals, there are no more than the number of subsets of the rationals, which is also $2^{\aleph_0}$

Comment: Any subset of the rationals can be put in order, but it won't in general be a _well_-ordering. So it won't in general define a monotone increasing sequence.

Comment: @TonyK:  good point.  I should use subsets of the naturals to get a lower bound, then use this argument to get an upper bound.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A different and perhaps slightly 'cleaner' approach to part 2: to each monotone sequence of rationals $p=\{p_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ we can define the 'difference' sequence $q=\{q_i\}$ via $q_1=p_1$, $q_{i+1}=p_{i+1}-p_i$; now the set $Q$ of sequences $\{q_i\}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}\times(\mathbb{Q}^+)^\mathbb{N}$, since the first element is an arbitrary rational and the rest of the sequence is made up of positive (since $p$ was monotone) rationals.  What's more, it's clear that to each sequence $\{q_i\}$ there's a unique monotone sequence $\{p_i\}$ of rationals (since we can recover $p$ from $q$ via $p_1=q_1$, $p_{i+1} = p_i+q_{i+1}$), so the set of all $p$-sequences is isomorphic to the set of all $q$-sequences.  But $\mathbb{Q}^+\cong\mathbb{N}$, and $\mathbb{Q}\cong\mathbb{N}$, so $Q\cong\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ $\cong\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ (since we can absorb the extra 'factor' of $\mathbb{N}$ easily), and of course the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ is just $\mathfrak{c}$.

To see where your argument falls short, note that you haven't provided an *isomorphism* — you've gone one direction by claiming that to each rational there is a sequence of rationals given by its decimal representation (for your example, $\{2, \frac{24}{10}, \frac{243}{100}, \ldots\}$), but this sequence isn't even necessarily monotone (what happens if your rational has terminating decimal expansion?).  More importantly, this isn't an equivalence, because it doesn't provide a 1-1 mapping in the other direction: *many* different monotone increasing rational sequences 'converge to' the same rational, and many don't converge at all, or don't converge to rational numbers.  For instance, your sequence could as easily have been $\{-1000, \frac{24}{10}, \frac{243}{100},\ldots\}$ and it would have mapped to the same rational number under your proposed equivalence.